# How to create custom keybinding for Ace editor

Tags: ace-editor

I simply copied the example from [documentation](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=howto):

```
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/javascript");

editor.commands.addCommand({
  name: 'myCommand',
  bindKey: {
    win: 'Ctrl-M',
    mac: 'Command-M'
  },
  exec: function(editor) {
    console.log("myCommand");
  },
  readOnly: true // false if this command should not apply in readOnly mode
});
```

This does not work. On pressing Command-M I do not see the debug print. What am I missing?

Jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kargirwar/tsLf9o5n/4/)

Comment: maybe there is something in your computer or browser capturing the key? The jsfiddle works both on mac and on windows with chrome

Comment: Oh yes, another application was gobbling up the keystrokes. Thanks for the hint!